# Where is the handy designer for setting Permissions and schema diagram designer in a SQL2005 Database Project in VSTS2008 Database Edition GDR RTM?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, database-project, gdr

I have just installed the GDR RTM version of Visual Studio Team System Database Edition GDR RTM.

It all seems to work wonderfully, but I seem to have to edit XML (Database.sqlpermissions) for specify SQL Permissions.

Am I missing something?

For that matter where is the schema diagram tool?

I understand GDR exposes alot for extending the Database Edition components, so am I supposed to wait for third party extensions to provide the diagram tool and permissions designer?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for some graphic designers and was disappointed when I didn't find any.

As I use it, it is looking better and better. Instead of graphic designers I design tables in database using SQL Server Management Studio and than reverse all to the scripts. Than I can make changes to the scripts directly and deploy new database version or continue to make changes in the database directly.

Round trip development works great.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I think they've missed the whole point with GDR, at least this version.

Source control and build automation is very nice, but the mainstay of database dev work is building objects and sprocs in the database, many of which are done using designers because it's just faster than cranking the TSQL. Since GDR doesn't cater for this, that design will continue to be done in Management Studio.

If people are using Management Studio to do their actual work, constantly syncing back to the VS model just to keep the source control up to date is a pain in the arse, which means it won't be done consistently, and even when it is it creates friction.

Round trip development does not work great.

Comment: No offense, but you don't exactly sound like the target market.  "The whole point" of GDR is to make it easier (or even possible) to manage database development and deployment using best practices like source control.  If you want to do your dev only in SSMS, then GDR probably isn't for you.

Comment: I don't think the benefits of source control shouldn't be at the expense of loosing any kind of designer support. I can crank TSQL as well as the next guy if I have to, but I also know I'm more productive given a decent design surface. Since GDR doesn't have one yet, it becomes unviable as a 'one stop shop', or at best condems you to lots of round-trip syncing.

Compare this with practically any other project type (including that for Analysis Services) where you can have your source-control cake and eat it too (get decent designer support). Are you suggesting GDR is just for TSQL junkies?

Comment: I should add that we are using GDR on my current project, and provided you work in a 'local dev database' model, you can establish a viable workflow. You just spend a lot of time syncing changes you've made to the database back to the model, when a handful of designers would enable you to work with the model as your primary environment.